# Possible Memory leak while erasing a vector of shared pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, vector

I have the following vector:

- `vector<boost::shared_ptr<Entity>> entities;`

In order to **reset** the vector I am using `erase`

- `entities.erase(entities.begin(), entities.end());`

---

## Question

is this procedure correct? Will it lead to memory leak? should I also delete FactClass?

---

## Class Entity

The constructor of class `Entity` takes as argument a vector of shared pointers of type `FactClass`

```
class Entity
{
public:
    Entity(std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<FactClass>>);
    vector<boost::shared_ptr<FactClass>> getClassFact() const;
private:
    vector<boost::shared_ptr<FactClass>> _listFacts;
};
```

---

## Class FactClass

The constructor of class `FactClass` takes as argument a vector of shared pointers of type `Fact` etc.

```
class FactClass
{
    public:
        FactClass(std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Fact>>);
        std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Fact>> getFacts() const;
    private:
        vector<boost::shared_ptr<Fact>> _fact;
};
```

---

Comment: I actually Wanted to reset the vector that's why I used `erase`. what is the difference if I use clear?

Comment: `clear` is correct too (and more explicit about intention).

Comment: @HaniGoc it's less typing, less errorprone and it's more expressive of intent

Comment: _"should I also delete FactClass?"_ If you still needed to do that, what purpose do you think `shared_ptr` would serve? Why would you bother to use it if it didn't do that for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clear() is defined in terms of erase(), which has linear complexity. In erase we provide range as parameters while clear is the erase implementation of the whole range.

- entities.erase(entities.begin(), entities.end());

is same as

- entities.clear();

And they leave the capacity() of the vector unchanged, so no memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

No, this will not leak memory (if the implementation of the `shared_ptr` is correct, which it is for boost's and std's `shared_ptr`). The moment the `shared_ptr` object is destroyed the memory will be released.

Comment: #Otomo so I don't have to go all the way down factClass and fact in order to reset the vector

Comment: @HaniGoc No. This is RAII. It's the essence of C++, according to many

Comment: @HaniGoc like @sehe said: Because `shared_ptr` is designed as **RAII** it is save to simply delete it or let it run out of scope. That is the purpose of smart pointers.

Comment: @Otomo equally important: `std::vector` also promises exception neutral destruction of elements on erase/clear/resize and destruction

Answer (score 0):

Your code will *not* leak, thanks to having **smart** pointers (`shared_ptr`) in the `vector`.

You should pay attention when having *owning raw pointers*, but when you have smart pointers, the destructor of the smart pointer will do proper cleanup.

(For the specific case of `shared_ptr`, there is a *reference count* associated to the pointers; so, the destructor will decrease the ref count of the associated smart pointer, and as soon as the ref count reaches zero, meaning that there is no more reference to the pointed object, this is *automatically* deleted.)

Anyway, I prefer calling the **`vector::clear()`** method, which is more explicit about your intent of "resetting" the vector.